# Rebuilding MySQL DB Tables of PHP script

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and web development. I have a PHP script that I downloaded for Hostel Management, but I don't have the .sql file of that project with the table details.

Can someone suggest me the best and fastest way to rebuild the database table using the PHP files/codes I already have?

Thanks

Comment: Sometimes the installation process creates the necessary tables. You should check your software documentation. On a side note, programming questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ask the original author for the SQL script.
2. If 1. failed, ask the original author for data base snapshots or backups. They probably can't and shouldn't give them to you.
3. If 2. is possible, ask the original author for restoring a backup themselves, then truncate all the data and give the schema back to you.
4. If everything else failed, read the code and once you understand it, you would be able to reverse engineer the SQL schema back.